# Deploying a full-stack Node JS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, react-fullstack

I have just completed a full stack attendance tracking app for my team. I am an intermediate level programmer and took this experience to learn webdev.
The app is isomorphic, fronted by HTML/CSS/Javascript and backed up Node; Express; Node Modules et all and MongoDB.

The app has been tested on localhost and is working fine.

Now this app is going to need to be installed or "perched" on a server, which also hosts several other of the team's internal applications.
I installed the npm-pack-all module; used this module to output a **.tgz** (which contains all source files).

I did an npm install of the **.tgz**, and ran the application on my localhost again, and it worked fine. I did this with the assumption that me distributing the **.tgz** to the administrator of the interal team server, will enable him to simply do **npm i install** of the **.tgz** and then run the application. But I am not sure if the **.tgz** has bundled node too; otherwise **npm i install .tgz** on the internal team server wouldn't work unless the internal team server has node installed on it already. Also the mongodb  database is missing, as the database has some pre-configured collections and data. This means that mongodb  will have to be installed on the internal team server, and I will have to create all those collections again, and all that initial data again.

Moving on from the aforementioned approach, I also wanted to explore other options. I was going through some threads, and noticed mention of **.exe** and **.msi** ; but I am not sure where to start.

My problem statement is this:

- I just need to distribute the completed application (source files
  with database) to the internal team server administrator.
- It will help if the administrator or anyone does not see the source
  files or    source files' content; or if that's not possible; at
  least the source    files need to be protected from being modified.
- It will help if the mongodb database and/or node js run-time is also
  installed (if not    already installed on that server) with the same
  'production-ready' configuration. In other words, in the case of
  mongodb, it will install with all the collections and the default
  data that was created during development.

Pls help!

Comment: Why don’t you use ‘Docker’?

Comment: Hi agtabesh, let me check on Docker documentation, and let you know if it solves my requirement.

Comment: Hi, agtabesh, after checking with the administrator, Docker is ruled out as the admin machines are using VMs. Containers are not allowed as of now. I was told by the admin that .msi is not applicable in the case of web apps. Not sure if that statement is true. The other options is to build a .exe; but when building the .exe i need the .exe code to check if node and mongo are installed on the server; if not fetch them from the internet and install them.